# mgo.v2, $sample alway return 1 same record

Tags: go, mgo

I need get 1 rand record from a collection. I check it on robo-mongo and it work great. But in golang project using mgo.v2, It always return the same record all the time . Is there any bug with the library, or I misunderstanding?

**I use "gopkg.in/mgo.v2". Here is my code:**

```
var err error

    pipe := col.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$match": bson.M{ "ad_group_id": worker.creative.AdGroupId }},
        {"$sample": bson.M{ "size": 1 }},
    })
    var resp []model.Coordinate
    err = pipe.All(&resp)

log.Print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++: ",resp)
```

=>

```
[
    {
        ObjectIdHex("...") ObjectIdHex("...") ObjectIdHex("...") 
        {
            Point [33 33]
        } 
        t3
    }
]
```

**Coordinate collections:**
[image]

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. This question in its current form is off-topic. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Please show what you have tried in code

Comment: Just add coding to question

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `mgo` package is invalid. If you use [`Pipeline.One()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Pipe.One), you should pass a target of a single `model.Coordinate` or `*model.Coordinate`:

```
var resp model.Coordinate
err = pipe.One(&resp)
```

Otherwise you get an error like:

```
Unsupported document type for unmarshalling: []model.Coordinate
```

If you're going to get a single result, then of course there is no need to specify a `size > 1` in the pipeline, so simply use:

```
{"$sample": bson.M{"size": 1}},
```

If you want to get multiple random results, then you may use a slice and [`Pipeline.All()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Pipe.All) like in this example:

```
pipe := col.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"ad_group_id": worker.creative.AdGroupId}},
    {"$sample": bson.M{"size": 2}},
})
var resp []model.Coordinate
err = pipe.All(&resp)
```

Comment: is it work for you? It look exactly what I code but "size: 1". In my side, It return the same record. only change when I restart server

Comment: @Peter_175 Yes, it works for me. Did you change `One()` to `All()`? Btw, which `mgo` package are you using? Is it `gopkg.in/mgo.v2`?

Comment: Ok I checked. It still return same record {Point [33 33]} t3 } .  I have setup 3 points (11,11) (22,22) (33,33).

Comment: @Peter_175 Please update your question with the exact code you're using, including the `model.Coordinate` type, also indicate which `mgo` package are you using.

Comment: @Peter_175 Do not edit this answer, edit your own question.

Comment: @Peter_175 The code you posted now works. So what is the question? Whenever you want a new random document, you have to call the `Pipe.All()` method.

Comment: If it match rand-condition I want to random() get 1 coordinate belong to that adgroup. But I test in "live" server, It func work, but always return point 33,33.

Comment: @Peter_175 Can you post all the documents in your coordinates collection (edit your question)? Maybe only that matches your filter?